# Fragment Changes when Screen is rotated

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragments, FragmentCity and Fragmentnumber1. When screen orientation changes on fragmentnumber1, it goes back to FragmentCity. Does anyone know how to solve this? I appreciate it if you could show me how to solve this issue

FragmentCity

```
public class FragmentCity extends Fragment {

    final String[] items = new String[]{"FC1", "FC2", "FC3", "FC4","FC5"
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.haz, container, false);

        ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.fir);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                    long arg3) {

                Fragment myFragment = null;

                switch (arg2) {

                    case 0:
                        myFragment = new Fragmentnumber1();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        myFragment = new Fragmentnumber2();
                        break;
                    case 2:

                        myFragment = new Fragmentnumber3();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        myFragment = new Fragmentnumber4();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        myFragment = new Fragmentnumber5();

                        break;

                }
                // update the main content by replacing fragments

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack("frag")
                        .replace(R.id.container2, myFragment)
                        .commit();


            }

        });
        return view;
    }



}
```

Fragmentnumber1

```
public class Fragmentnumber1 extends Fragment {

    final String[] items = new String[]{"num1", "num2", "num3"
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.haz, container, false);

        ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.fir);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                    long arg3) {

                Fragment myFragment = null;
                switch (arg2){
                    case 0:
                        myFragment = new num1();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        myFragment = new num2();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        myFragment = new num3();
                        break;

                }
                // update the main content by replacing fragments
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null)
                        .replace(R.id.container2, myFragment)
                        .commit();
            }

        });
        return view;
    }




}
```

Comment: Try adding `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` to the Activity (in the manifest) that contains these two Fragments, then tell me if you have the same problem.

Comment: I get an error that says that the Fragments are not assignable to `android.app.Activity`. I tried this code `  <activity android:name=".Fragmentnumber" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>`

Comment: Fragmentnumber is name of your Activity?

Comment: Correct, fragments <> activities. Your fragments are contained in an Activity, probably something named `MainActivity`. You need to add `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` to THAT activity

Comment: Adding it to the `MainActivity` works! Thank you!

Comment: @NewGuy117, Added my answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try adding the following line to your containing activity (probably `MainActivity`) in the manifest

`<activity android:name=".MainActivity" 
  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>`

This will allow the Activity to maintain it's state across orientation changes.

Answer (score 0):

You have not posted code of activity class but i am guessing that you have loaded FragmentCity fragment in onCreate of your activity

So when you change orientation it again call onCreate and load FragmentCity fragment so by putting proper condition you can manage it.

Comment: Sorry, what activity class? I'm using FragmentCity to get Fragmentnumber1 via onclick. I don't understand.

Comment: Class in which you are loading Fragment. Like MainActivity

Comment: Oh, I see. As what ElliotM suggested to me, I've added `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize` at MainActivity in the manifest file and it worked.