# Error when Android change orientation in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

Hello everybody

I have an Activity that host a FrameLayout, because I want to maintain this activity as the Main activity for the application change with differents Fragments depending on the menu option.

The problem is that in the fragments I'm doing various AsyncTask to pulling data from the server, I know there is various approach about this theme in this forum, but I don't find the right one for my case, so I need your help to get this work.

This is a fragment of the Activity:

```
public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected NavigationView navigationView;
    protected ListView lv_menu_gateway;
    protected ListView lv_menu_options;
    protected AppManager manager;
    public Identity myIdentity;
    protected List<Device> devices;
    public String lastDeviceConnected;
    public DeviceData deviceData;
    protected ProgressBar pb_dashboardGeneral;
    protected List<com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster.poco.Menu> menus;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        manager = AppManager.getManager(getApplication());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        pb_dashboardGeneral = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.pb_dashboardGeneral);
        pb_dashboardGeneral.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pb_dashboardGeneral.bringToFront();
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        lv_menu_gateway = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_menu_gateway);
        lv_menu_options = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_menu_options);
        new LoadIdentityObject(this).execute();
        GetListOfMenusOptions();
        lv_menu_options.setAdapter(new ListMenuAdapter(this, menus));
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_layout_container, new fragmentDashboard());
        transaction.commit();

        lv_menu_gateway.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                manager.SaveSharedLastDeviceConnected(devices.get(position).getDeviceNumber());
                new LoadDeviceData(getParent()).execute();
                drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for the Fragment as you could see I have 4 different nested AsynckTask that I'm using to pull the whole data that I need to show in the screen:

```
public class fragmentDashboard extends Fragment {

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    protected AppManager manager;
    protected Identity myIdentity;
    protected Account myAccount;
    protected String lastDeviceConnected;
    protected DeviceData deviceData;
    protected TextView lb_account_info_name;
    protected TextView lb_account_address;
    protected List<Notification> notifications;
    protected ListView lv_dashboard_notifications;
    protected GridView gv_house_mode;
    protected List<HouseMode> houseModes;
    protected GridView gv_sensors_devices;
    protected List<Sensor> sensors;

    public static fragmentDashboard newInstance() {
        return new fragmentDashboard();
    }

    public fragmentDashboard() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
        manager = AppManager.getManager(this.getActivity().getApplication());
        myIdentity = manager.RetrieveSharedIdentityObject();
        lastDeviceConnected = manager.RetrieveSharedLastDeviceConnect();
        lb_account_address = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lb_account_address);
        lb_account_info_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lb_account_info_name);
        lv_dashboard_notifications = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lv_dashboard_notifications);
        gv_house_mode = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gv_house_mode);
        gv_sensors_devices = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gv_sensors_devices);
        new LoadAccountInformation(getActivity()).execute();
        new LoadDeviceDataNotification(getActivity()).execute();
        new LoadDeviceHouseMode(getActivity()).execute();
        new LoadSensorsList(getActivity()).execute();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

    public class LoadAccountInformation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Message>{

        public Activity activity;

        public LoadAccountInformation(Activity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        protected Message doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try{
                if(myIdentity != null) {
                    myAccount = manager.GetAccount(myIdentity.getServerAccount(), myIdentity.getServerAccountToken(), myIdentity.getIdentityAccountNumber());
                    if (myAccount != null) {
                        return new Message(0, getResources().getString(R.string.msg_account_ok_account));
                    }else{
                        return new Message(1, getResources().getString(R.string.msg_account_error_account));
                    }
                }else {
                    return new Message(1, getResources().getString(R.string.msg_account_error_identity));
                }
            }catch (Exception ex){
                return new Message(1, getResources().getString(R.string.msg_account_error_account));
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Message message) {
            if(message.getMessageType() == 0){
                String name = "";
                String address = "";
                String city = "";
                String state = "";
                String zipCode = "";
                if(myAccount.getAccountFirstName() == null && myAccount.getAccountLastName() == null){
                    name = "";
                }else{
                    if(myAccount.getAccountFirstName() != null && myAccount.getAccountLastName() == null){
                        name = myAccount.getAccountFirstName();
                    }else {
                        if((myAccount.getAccountFirstName() == null) && (myAccount.getAccountLastName() != null)){
                            name = myAccount.getAccountLastName();
                        }else {
                            name = myAccount.getAccountLastName() + ", " + myAccount.getAccountFirstName();
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(myAccount.getAccountAddress1() == null && myAccount.getAccountAddress2() == null){
                    address = "";
                }else{
                    if(myAccount.getAccountAddress1() != null && myAccount.getAccountAddress2() == null){
                        address = myAccount.getAccountAddress1();
                    }else {
                        if(myAccount.getAccountAddress1() == null && myAccount.getAccountAddress2() != null){
                            address = myAccount.getAccountAddress2();
                        }else{
                            address = myAccount.getAccountAddress1() + ", " + myAccount.getAccountAddress2();
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(myAccount.getAccountCity() != null){
                    if(!address.isEmpty()){
                        city = ", " + myAccount.getAccountCity();
                    }else{
                        city = myAccount.getAccountCity();
                    }
                }
                if(myAccount.getAccountState() != null){
                    if(!address.isEmpty() || !city.isEmpty()){
                        state = ", " + myAccount.getAccountState();
                    }else{
                        state = myAccount.getAccountState();
                    }
                }
                if(myAccount.getAccountPostalCode() != null){
                    if(!address.isEmpty() || !city.isEmpty() || !state.isEmpty()){
                        zipCode = ", " + myAccount.getAccountPostalCode();
                    }else{
                        zipCode = myAccount.getAccountPostalCode();
                    }
                }
                lb_account_info_name.setText(name);
                String addressToShow = address + city + state + zipCode;
                lb_account_address.setText(addressToShow);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this.activity.getApplicationContext(), message.getMessageContent(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    public class LoadDeviceDataNotification extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Message>{

        private Activity activity;

        public LoadDeviceDataNotification(Activity activity){
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        protected Message doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try{
                lastDeviceConnected = manager.RetrieveSharedLastDeviceConnect();
                if(lastDeviceConnected != null){
                    deviceData = manager.RetrieveDeviceDataObject();
                }
                return new Message(0, getString(R.string.msg_gateway_ok_devicedata));
            }catch (Exception ex){
                return new Message(1, getString(R.string.msg_gateway_error_devicedata));
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Message message) {
            if(message.getMessageType() == 0){
                if(deviceData != null){
                    //Notifications
                    notifications = new ArrayList<>();
                    if(!deviceData.getDeviceDataComment().isEmpty()){
                        notifications.add(new Notification(1, deviceData.getDeviceDataComment()));
                    }else{
                        notifications.add(new Notification(1, getResources().getString(R.string.notification_default)));
                    }
                    lv_dashboard_notifications.setAdapter(new ListNotificationsAdapter(notifications, this.activity));
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public class LoadDeviceHouseMode extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Message>{

        private Activity activity;

        public LoadDeviceHouseMode(Activity activity){
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        protected Message doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try{
                lastDeviceConnected = manager.RetrieveSharedLastDeviceConnect();
                if(lastDeviceConnected != null){
                    deviceData = manager.RetrieveDeviceDataObject();
                }
                return new Message(0, getString(R.string.msg_gateway_ok_devicedata));
            }catch (Exception ex){
                return new Message(1, getString(R.string.msg_gateway_error_devicedata));
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Message message) {
            if(message.getMessageType() == 0){
                if(deviceData != null){
                    LoadHouseModeGridView();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    protected void LoadHouseModeGridView(){
        //Building the list
        houseModes = new ArrayList<>();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_home_48dp);
        if(deviceData != null) {
            if (deviceData.getDeviceDataMode() == 1) {
                houseModes.add(new HouseMode(1, getString(R.string.lb_house_mode_home), true, bitmap));
            } else {
                houseModes.add(new HouseMode(1, getString(R.string.lb_house_mode_home), false, bitmap));
            }
        }else{
            houseModes.add(new HouseMode(1, getString(R.string.lb_house_mode_home), false, bitmap));
        }
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_away_48dp);
        if(deviceData != null) {
            if (deviceData.getDeviceDataMode() == 2) {
                houseModes.add(new HouseMode(2, getString(R.string.lb_house_mode_away), true, bitmap));
            } else {
                houseModes.add(new HouseMode(2, getString(R.string.lb_house_mode_away), false, bitmap));
            }
        }else{
            houseModes.add(new HouseMode(2, getString(R.string.lb_house_mode_away), false, bitmap));
        }
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_night_48dp);
        if(deviceData != null) {
            if (deviceData.getDeviceDataMode() == 3) {
                houseModes.add(new HouseMode(3, getString(R.string.lb_house_mode_night), true, bitmap));
            } else {
                houseModes.add(new HouseMode(3, getString(R.string.lb_house_mode_night), false, bitmap));
            }
        }else{
            houseModes.add(new HouseMode(3, getString(R.string.lb_house_mode_night), false, bitmap));
        }
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_vacation_48dp);
        if(deviceData != null) {
            if (deviceData.getDeviceDataMode() == 4) {
                houseModes.add(new HouseMode(4, getString(R.string.lb_house_mode_vacation), true, bitmap));
            } else {
                houseModes.add(new HouseMode(4, getString(R.string.lb_house_mode_vacation), false, bitmap));
            }
        }else{
            houseModes.add(new HouseMode(4, getString(R.string.lb_house_mode_vacation), false, bitmap));
        }
        gv_house_mode.setAdapter(new ListHouseModeAdapter(getActivity(), houseModes));
    }

    public class LoadSensorsList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Message>{

        private Activity activity;

        public LoadSensorsList(Activity activity){
            this.activity = activity;
        }
        @Override
        protected Message doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                sensors = Sensor.GenerateSensorList(manager);
                return new Message(0, getString(R.string.msg_sensors_ok));
            }catch (Exception ex){
                return new Message(1, getString(R.string.msg_sensors_error));
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Message message) {
            if(message.getMessageType() == 0){
                gv_sensors_devices.setAdapter(new ListSensorsAdapter(activity, sensors));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

For the fragment class "fragmentDashboard" I have to different layout Xml one for portrait and other one for landscape to manage a different look when the user rotate.

Finally the problem occurred when I rotate the device I got the following error and the application crash:

```
11-03 09:43:48.890 29987-30025/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
11-03 09:43:48.890 29987-30025/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster, PID: 29987
11-03 09:43:48.890 29987-30025/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-03 09:43:48.890 29987-30025/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
11-03 09:43:48.890 29987-30025/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
11-03 09:43:48.890 29987-30025/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
11-03 09:43:48.890 29987-30025/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
11-03 09:43:48.890 29987-30025/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
11-03 09:43:48.890 29987-30025/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-03 09:43:48.890 29987-30025/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-03 09:43:48.890 29987-30025/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
11-03 09:43:48.890 29987-30025/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment fragmentDashboard{447e431} not attached to Activity
11-03 09:43:48.890 29987-30025/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:788)
11-03 09:43:48.890 29987-30025/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster.activities.fragmentDashboard$LoadAccountInformation.doInBackground(fragmentDashboard.java:148)
11-03 09:43:48.890 29987-30025/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster.activities.fragmentDashboard$LoadAccountInformation.doInBackground(fragmentDashboard.java:126)
11-03 09:43:48.890 29987-30025/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
11-03 09:43:48.890 29987-30025/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-03 09:43:48.890 29987-30025/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
11-03 09:43:48.890 29987-30025/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
11-03 09:43:48.890 29987-30025/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
11-03 09:43:48.890 29987-30025/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I did some tests and the problem is with the AsyncTask calls, when I comment the AsyncTask calls everything work fine with the screen rotation.

Anyone have an idea of what approach I have to take to solve this problem?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Please post the full logcat output

Comment: Thanks @Nanoc it is done.

Comment: This is a fairly common issue that could generally be solved by the answer to this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32503305/fragment-changes-when-screen-is-rotated/32504393#32504393

Comment: @ElliotM thank you for your answer but i have read a few posts here that explain why this approach is not the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In method `doInBackground` you invoke method `getResources`. But, when screen rotate, your Activity recreating, and your fragment some time not attached to Activity. Therefore you can't `getResources` at that time. You can initialize your Messages before, for instance in AsyncTask constructor. Or you can use in class `Message`, in constructor only string resource reference, for instance:

```
new Message(0, R.string.msg_account_ok_account)
```

(of course you need modify constructor)

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, you are right with your comment but, I removed all the getResources() in the doInBackground but I still have the problem but now in the onPostExecute method, and in the method onPostExecuteMethod it is very necessary to use it, I can't remove i think

Comment: AsyncTask have many issues, main issue - they are poorly tied to the activity life cycle. You can try other background solutions.As for me best is https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava

Comment: Thank you very much I will check on your suggestion, so I'm going to mark your answer as the right one, thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help! If you choose RxJava for you project, you can try https://github.com/evant/rxloader. It will help to you handle activity  Android's activity lifecyle. Also you can try alternative solution - Bolts-Android

Comment: thanks a lot again, yes I will check on that. Somebody don't like the post because rate the post negative, I don't know why? We are here to help don't you think?

Answer (score -2):

One of your calls to getResources() is throwing an exception caused by the dash condition created by the recreation of the fragment.

Maybe you could just store a static reference to Resources while asynctask is running.

That should fix your problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Dont use static references to your resources! The reason I warned against this is that static references to Contexts can cause memory leaks!

Comment: Was meaning to store it while asynctask is running to set it to null after that. is that still that bad?

Comment: Please, read this blog: http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Comment: Not telling nothing new to me, still thinking that if you set it to null just after you finish your work it should not be any problem.

Comment: Whatever, it's not best architectural solution.